# Why does the suffix of "iodine" sound different in American and British English?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, science

As an American, I noticed *Fluorine* and *Iodine*, though clearly sharing the same ending (and this was corroborated by etymonline.com; both contain the same chemical suffix) sounded different. *Fluorine* has an ending that sounds like "een", and *Iodine* has an ending that sounds like "ine" should sound if you say it aloud. *Bromine*, *Chlorine*, and *Astatine* also have an "een" ending, so clearly *Iodine* is an outlier. I then went on en.wiktionary.org to check it out, and it turns out the British pronounce it correctly, whereas the Americans do not. I searched all my usual sources and some more, but nothing could explain this difference. Any help?

Comment: If you know nothing about any of the other terms and you encounter "iodine" for the first time, how would you pronounce it?  Consider how you pronounce the word "dine".

Comment: And where do they say *EEohdeen*? ;-)

Comment: Consider that "iodine" is/was a common antiseptic, and at one time a bottle of "tincture of iodine" was in virtually every medicine cabinet in the US.  But the common person had no cause to ever encounter fluorine and bromine, and only a vague familiarity with chlorine.  As to astatine, I had to look it up.

Comment: Good point; _iodine_ probably has passed into colloquial English by now, while all the others are mainly used scientifically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any good explanation.

I checked this in Fowler (originally 1926; re-published 2009). He writes that *iodine, bromine, chlorine* and *fluorine* were at the time all given  with /ɪn/ as the main pronunciation in the OED, with /aɪ/ as an allowed alternative. He also thinks that "iodine" generally had /aɪ/ in popular usage at his time, unlike the other three.

Apparently the prevalence of different pronunciations has shifted since his time. As you note, the pronunciation with /iː/ seems to be common in modern British English (the OED now lists it first). In general, words ending in the suffix *-ine* have very variable pronunciation, unrelated to any etymological distinctions (e.g. *divine, bovine* vs. *marine* vs. *genuine*). It's somewhat comparable to the variability in the pronunciation of *-ile.* Although some, such as [John Walker](https://archive.org/stream/acriticalpronou00conggoog#page/n476/mode/2up/search/senile), have attempted to prescribe /ɪl~l̩/ vs. /aɪl/ on the basis of Latin vowel length, it seems quite arbitrary to use this as a criterion of correct pronunciation today, especially since /aɪ/ is actually stigmatized in the pronunciation of the word *[genuine](https://books.google.com/books?id=YtojrMr0Ft4C&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=beastly%20pronunciation%20genuine&source=bl&ots=FMJEVSgiog&sig=ZWAJrJJRJXCCxI8l0X7aA44SeRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6uImDw6nRAhVi7oMKHU2ZBscQ6AEIMTAD#v=snippet&q=genuine&f=false)* which is from Latin *genuīnus* (and as far as I know, /aɪ/ is unheard of in *doctrine,* from Latin *doctrīna*).

Another oddity is that "machine", which in Latin had a *short* vowel in the second syllable and was stressed on the first vowel (*māchina*), is in modern English pronounced with stressed /iːn/ in the last syllable due to coming through French. (This word doesn't have the same suffix as the other *-ine* words, but it ends in the same letters.)

Comment: In Middle French where we got the word from, *machine* had three syllables not two; its stress pattern is unclear because I’m not certain when French lost phonemic stress. However, other Western Romance languages have *máquina* (ES,PT,Gal), *màquina* (Cat),  *macchina* (IT) — all stressed on the first of their three faithful syllables. I am quite suspicious of the notion that French advanced the stress syllable by one before it lost stress altogether.

Comment: @tchrist: Well, I don't think "machine" was a natural development from Latin "machina", it was probably a learned borrowing. As far as I know, Latin /k/ or /kʰ/ didn't normally develop to French "ch" before "i", and Latin short unstressed "i" was usually dropped in French in positions like this (compare *ordre* < *ordinem,* *femme* < *feminam,* *homme* < *hominem*). So it wouldn't surprise me if the stress was placed in a different place from in Latin.